# Angular2 Google Maps events -> UI changes are delayed, why?

Tags: google-maps, user-interface, angular, google-maps-api-3

I have an Angluar2 app that includes the Google Maps JS API. I load Google Maps like this:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KE‌​Y"> </script>
```

I listen to events on the map like this:

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
  zoom: zoom
});
this.map.addListener('click', () => {
  console.log("Map click");
  this.key++;
});
```

I show the key in the template:

```
<div>{{key}}</div>
```

Updating the `key`, using a regular function takes immediate effect in the UI. Updating the `key` using the above function takes 10-20 seconds to update. I can see that the event is immediately triggered in the console. If I switch tabs, for example: My-App -> Another Page -> back to My-App, the value is updated immediately as well.

Therefore, I figured that the UI changes are not detected and updated my above code to:

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) {

.... code in between ....

this.map.addListener('click', () => {
  console.log("Map click");
  this.key++;
  this.ref.detectChanges();
});
```

This updates the `key` immediately.

Why are events from Google Maps not recognized immediately as usual?

BTW: This also happens with other Events, for example center_change or Marker click.

Comment: vanila ggooogle maps?

Comment: Since there is no official Angular2 package that supports Google Maps I just load it using: `<script 
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY">
    </script>`. Updated my question.

Comment: put this script into head

Comment: @RomanC I have the script in my head section. Everything works, except that the events are delayed. See my question.

Comment: Because this code is running outside angular zone

Comment: @yurzui, wow that was the key-word I was looking for. Thanks! Do you want to add this as an answer with some more details and an example? Otherwise I can do it myself?

Answer (score 2):

When using third party JS libraries in Angular2, you will need to make sure the library's events are being fired within Angular's zone (https://medium.com/@MertzAlertz/what-the-hell-is-zone-js-and-why-is-it-in-my-angular-2-6ff28bcf943e#.kumw91vmr).

When using the Google Maps JS API, the events fired from clicks on the map and markers are fired outside of the Angular zone.

There is an Angular2 core module called NgZone that will help you with this. By importing the NgZone module, and then specifying that you want to run the map click events within the zone, you can ensure that Angular2 detects the events immediately:

Within your map component, import NgZone:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
```

Within the component's constructor, declare NgZone:

```
constructor(private ref: ChangeDetectorRef, public zone: NgZone) {...}
```

Within your marker's click event, run your code inside the zone's 'run' method:

```
let me = this;
this.map.addListener('click', () => {
    me.zone.run(() => {
        console.log("Map click");
        this.key++;
        this.ref.detectChanges();
    });
});
```

Comment: Can u help me with this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53295654/angular-google-maps-markers-are-not-loaded-until-the-user-clicks-on-map